# C# asp.net /Boolean /Arduino

Tags: c#, asp.net, arduino, boolean

Hello i have one button on webform and i would like that on first click it send "1" to arduino  on second click "0" and continusly like that, i coded it like that:

```
Boolean test == false;
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (test == false)
        {
            serijska_vrata.Open();
            serijska_vrata.Write("1");
            serijska_vrata.Close();
            test = true;
        }
         if(test == true)
        {
            serijska_vrata.Open();
            serijska_vrata.Write("0");
            serijska_vrata.Close();
            test = false;

        } 

    }
```

Serijska_vrata is name of SerialPort;
I have a felling like boolean always resets to false, and never get value "true", what can i do to repair this, please help, i`am a beginner in programming.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: where are you initializing test???

Comment: Make sure test variable in global scope instead of method scope.Make it static variable and try

Comment: where are you putting test=false in your code?

Comment: Thank you it worked i just had to add static. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will never write true, because in ASP.Net every time you post back to the server the whole code will be executed and rendered as HTML then the server will dispose the whole objects, at the next time the server will create test object again and assign false to it,
the best solution is to save the status of the Boolean in a hidden value, and read it from it and update it after that, or you can use session, but you need to handle the session state if it's expired.

Comment: Can you help me with this method to hide the boolean, because i think i will need in future, now it worked with static bool test = false; but in the future i will need to get some data from arduino evry 2 seconds, i have solved this on winforms with backgorundworker, i dont know how i will do this with aspnet

Answer (score 0):

This is a webform application , that means you can click this button in everywhere,So where do you want keep "test" state with current login user or current Session?
If you want keep "test" state in current Session,please try use ViewState to save "test" value.

---

```
private bool _test;
public bool test

{
    get{
        bool.TryParse(ViewState["test"],out _test);
        return _test;
    }
   set{
        ViewState["test"]=value;
    }
}


protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (test == false)
        {
            serijska_vrata.Open();
            serijska_vrata.Write("1");
            serijska_vrata.Close();
            test = true;
        }
         if(test == true)
        {
            serijska_vrata.Open();
            serijska_vrata.Write("0");
            serijska_vrata.Close();
            test = false;

        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to check for == true,

```
if(test)
```

is the same as

```
if (test==true)
```

You need to change you logic slightly.  Switch the two statements round.

```
   if (test)
    {
        serijska_vrata.Open();
        serijska_vrata.Write("0");
        serijska_vrata.Close();
        test = false;        }
    // Add the else here and remove the if otherwise it
    // will execute the if statement and test will always be false
    // It also helps if test is not initialized.
    else
    {
        serijska_vrata.Open();
        serijska_vrata.Write("1");
        serijska_vrata.Close();
        test = true;
    }
```